# Recursion in FP-Growth Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, recursion, data-mining, fpgrowth

I am trying to implement FP-Growth (frequent pattern mining) algorithm in Java. I have built the tree, but have difficulties with conditional FP tree construction; I do not understand what recursive function should do. Given a list of frequent items (in increasing order of frequency counts) - a header, and a tree (list of Node class instances) what steps should the function take?

[image: image retrieved from https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiT4Oeeg53lAhWPhOAKHUdSAmkQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FPseudocode-FP-tree-Purba-30_fig2_330783065&psig=AOvVaw3fyRRKroFZwnASsE-vuMZy&ust=1571186297476542]

I have hard time understanding this pseudocode above. Are alpha and Betha nodes in the Tree, and what do generate and construct functions do?

I can do FP-Growth by hand, but find the implementation extremely confusing. If that could help, I can share my code for FP-Tree generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. alpha is the prefix that lead to this specific prefix tree
2. beta is the new prefix (of the tree to be constructed)
3. the generate line means something like: add to result set the pattern beta with support `anItem.support`
4. the construct function creates the new patterns from which the new tree is created

An example of the construct function (bottom up way) would be something like:

```
function construct(Tree, anItem)   
    conditional_pattern_base = empty list
    in Tree find all nodes with tag = anItem
    for each node found:
       support = node.support
       conditional_pattern = empty list
       while node.parent != root_node
            conditional_pattern.append(node.parent)
            node = node.parent
       conditional_pattern_base.append( (conditional_pattern, support))
    return conditional_pattern_base
```